# Why hasOwnProperty returns false on a constructor function but string property returns true when accessed without instantiating the function

Tags: javascript

I basically understand, **hasOwnProperty** method in JavaScript is used to check whether the object has the specified property as its own property.

But the behaviour I checked in browser console below got me downright confused.
Can someone explain me why this is happening.
I did try finding existing answer, but couldnt find a relevant link.

[image]

Comment: [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: `Shape` and `s` are two different objects. They just happen to have a property with the same name. Those properties are not related in any way.

Comment: In other words: "Shape" is an object. An instance of a "Shape" is an object. They're not the *same* object, and that they share some property names is coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the typeof Shape it will return you a "function"
but typeof s will return "object"

When you call
        var s = new Shape();
Shape will considered as class
but name and size are members of Shabe class.

Default constructor will called on new Shape() and creates a object of Shape.